# How do I get the IP address of a local hostname in local network in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking

how do I get the IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.1) of a local hostname (e.g. "myComputer") on my local network in swift?

I tried this:

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"www.google.com").takeRetainedValue();
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .Addresses, nil);
var success: Boolean = 0;
let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray;
if (addresses.count > 0){
    let theAddress = addresses[0] as NSData;
    var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)
    if getnameinfo(UnsafePointer(theAddress.bytes), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
        &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
            if let numAddress = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                println(numAddress)
            }
    }
}
```

This works fine for addresses like "www.google.com" but not for hostnames like "myComputer"

I tried it in Xcode Simulator. There it works, but not on my iPhone

I'll get the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

... in Line 4.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local hostnames such as **myComputer** will only be available to your iPhone if it's DNS server is configured to resolve them (or they are in the hosts file).

To resolve **myComputer** on your iPhone, you would need to have your iPhone configured to use a local DNS server that would serve IP addresses for the hostnames of the machines on your local network.

The error you're seeing relates to not getting a result. You'll need to check that the host resolves (`CFHostStartInfoResolution` provides a result for this):

```
let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,"www.google.com").takeRetainedValue();
var success : Boolean = CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .Addresses, nil);
if success > 0 {
    success = 0;
    let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
    if (addresses.count > 0){
        let theAddress = addresses[0] as! NSData;
        var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)
        if getnameinfo(UnsafePointer(theAddress.bytes), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
            &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
            if let numAddress = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                println(numAddress)
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    println("Host not found!")
}
```

Comment: so you mean something like that?

let addresses: NSArray?
addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray;
            if addresses == nil {
                return ""
            }

- doesn't work, too

Comment: See my updated answer for a complete solution, the error you're seeing actually happens even before you get a response from `CFHostGetAddressing`.